# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

Trying to create a program to change a username stored in an external CSV file by importing it then writing it to a list and appending the list.

I originally tried using remove function that didn't work, then tried pop()

```
import csv
Usernames = []
x = int(input('How many user name u want to enter?: '))
for i in range(x):
    file = open('usernames.csv','a+')
    username = input('Enter the username: ')
    file.write(username)
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()

f = open ('usernames.csv','r')
with open ('usernames.csv','r') as fi1e:
    reader = csv.reader(fi1e)
    for row in reader:
        Username = row
        Usernames.append(Username)
print (Usernames)
f.close()

change_from = input ('What username would you like to change?: ')
Usernames.pop(change_from)
```

I expect it to remove the username from the list. But instead it says 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: Is the input supposed to be an integer (index) or string (username)?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) for the list `pop()` method indicates that the argument passed to it should be an integer index, not a string. Use the `remove()` method, instead.

Comment: If you are trying to remove a given *element* from a list, use the `remove` method.

Comment: I already tried using remove but that would say error Usernames.x (x) not found

Comment: Then what you entered wasn't a username in the list.

Comment: The username was in the list

Answer (score 0):

This is because `input` returns a string.  You can convert it to an integer using `int`  like this:    `int(change_from)` and then you'll get the type you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert your change_from variable to int:

```
change_from = int(input('What username would you like to change?: '))
Usernames.pop(change_from)
```

Comment: This would be correct if the user enters the index of the item. And I doubt that's what they're doing

Comment: @blitzblade if it is not then why is the variable named to change_from ? that sounds like they want the user to enter an index to change from it

Comment: @basilisk In that case, they shouldn't be ignoring the return value of `pop`.

Comment: Right. But from a user's point of view, the question reads "What username would you like to change?:". That's what actually got me thinking they're to input the username.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `pop` function correctly. See the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.pop([i])
>   Remove the item at the given position in the list, and
>   return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the
>   last item in the list. (The square brackets around the i in the method
>   signature denote that the parameter is optional, not that you should
>   type square brackets at that position. You will see this notation
>   frequently in the Python Library Reference.)

You need to find the index of the string to want to remove and pass it to `pop` as below:

```
>>> a=['first', 'second', 'third']
>>> p = a.index('second')
>>> p
1
>>> a.pop(p)
'second'
>>> a
['first', 'third']
```

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it's inefficient because it requires (implicitly) searching the list twice. It would better to do it with one call to the list `remove()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`pop()` takes the index of the item as argument. In this case, you should check if what the user entered is in your list. If so, what index is it? Then use that integer.

```py
change_from = input ('What username would you like to change?: ')
if change_from in Usernames:
    Usernames.pop(Usernames.index(change_from))
```

Update:
Since you don't care what is being returned, use `remove()`. Also use `strip()` to ensure newline is removed.

Here's the full thing. The row is an array so you need to pick the first item.

```py
import csv
Usernames = []
x = int(input('How many user name u want to enter?: '))
for i in range(x):
    file = open('usernames.csv','a+')
    username = input('Enter the username: ')
    file.write(username)
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()

f = open ('usernames.csv','r')
with open ('usernames.csv','r') as fi1e:
    reader = csv.reader(fi1e)
    for row in reader:
        Username = row[0]
        Usernames.append(Username.strip())
print (Usernames)
f.close()

change_from = input ('What username would you like to change?: ')
if change_from.strip() in Usernames:
    Usernames.remove(change_from)
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the username from the list

Comment: Probably the `\n` is still attached to the username so it doesn't match. Does the block under the if run?

Comment: I agree to using `remove()` tho. This works but is not the most efficient way.

Comment: Yes the username is appended to list for example i want to replace a with b it prints out the following list [['a'],'b']]

Comment: I get it. Let me rewrite the answer to fix it.